# org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.domain.ServerCreated API

Tags: java, openstack, openstack-nova, jclouds

```
CreateServerOptions options = CreateServerOptions.Builder.adminPass("password");
ServerCreated serverCreated = serverApi.create(computeData.getServerName(), computeData.getImageId(), flavourId, options);
```

The code above throws the error:

```
"com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 5"
```

The server is created, but the error restricts me from proceeding further. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a bug due to some kind of version incompatibility. Here's [How to Report a Bug to Apache jclouds](http://jclouds.apache.org/documentation/userguide/bug-report/). The important things we'll need from you in this case are the jclouds version and the OpenStack version (e.g. Folsom, Grizzly, Havana) that you're using.

The bug is being worked on at [JCLOUDS-374](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-374)

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I'm using jclouds-compute-1.5.1.(openstack-nova-1.5.1) and Essex Openstack version.